# Identifying and collecting potential duplicates in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I've got an array like the following one that I want to identify duplicates in;

```
$names = array(
    array("Name" => "John Smith",      "ID" => 65), 
    array("Name" => "Richard Johnson", "ID" => 96), 
    array("Name" => "John Smith",      "ID" => 1105),
    ...
)
```

There's a lot of similar questions, but most just involve returning a true/false value if there's a duplicate, or simply remove the duplicates. I apologize if there's a question that's identical to this one with a result, I looked but could not find something that would work for my situation.

I just want to identify a pair of arrays that contain the same "Name" values, but possibly different "ID" values. I understand that this may cause duplicate results with inverted values, but I think I can figure that out on my own. I do NOT want to remove the duplicate values, I only want to identify them.

Ideally it would return an array similar to the following (or something similar);

```
$dupes = array(
    array(
        array("Name" => John Smith, "ID" => 65),
        array("Name" => John Smith, "ID" => 1105)
    )
)
```

which I could then process into a more refined and user friendly array.

I was thinking of using a recursive in_array function, or possibly a second working array. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `foreach` loop first? That should always be your go-to solution; you can refactor to use built-in functions afterwards.

Comment: @El_Vanja I'm trying one out right now, but the array has 16k+ entries in it, and my only idea is for every name compare it to every other name, but that's like 16k^16k operations

Comment: That's definitely not a good approach, but you don't need to compare them all. Grouping can be applied to achieve what you need (see the answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you just loop through and create a new array using the name as the key? test the below here: http://phptester.net/

```
$names = array(
    array("Name" => 'John Smith', "ID" => 65), 
    array("Name" => 'Richard Johnson', "ID" => 96), 
    array("Name" => 'John Smith', "ID" => 1105)
);

$users = [];
foreach($names as $usersArray){
    
    $users[$usersArray['Name']]['ids'][] = $usersArray['ID'];
    
}

print_r($users);
```

or simply:

```
$names = array(
    array("Name" => 'John Smith', "ID" => 65), 
    array("Name" => 'Richard Johnson', "ID" => 96), 
    array("Name" => 'John Smith', "ID" => 1105)
);

$users = [];
foreach($names as $usersArray){
    
    $users[$usersArray['Name']][] = $usersArray['ID'];
    
}

print_r($users);
```

Comment: All that's left to do after this is filtering the result by the count of IDs under a name (it's kind of implied, but it's better to be explicit for any future readers who are beginners).

Comment: This works great too! This also doesn't cause any memory problems and seems to work very fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For this type of situation, you would typically want to define some logic for creating a hash from the values in your records in order to determine equality. Once you have that defined, you can use simple looping and associative arrays to keep track of which records have duplicates.

```
<?php
/**
 * Define an algorithm for equality between records.
 *
 * @param $record
 * @return string
 */
function generateHashForUserRecord($record)
{
    return sha1($record['Name']);
}

$names = [
    ['Name' => 'John Smith', 'ID' => 65],
    ['Name' => 'Richard Johnson', 'ID' => 96],
    ['Name' => 'John Smith', 'ID' => 1105]
];

// This map will be an populated with all records, keyed by hash
$hashBuffer = [];

// Buffer for hashes that are associated with more than one record
$duplicateHashes = [];

// This will be populated with the duplicate records
$duplicateRecords = [];

// Iterate through all of the records
foreach($names as $currRecord)
{
    // Generate a has for the record
    $currHash = generateHashForUserRecord($currRecord);

    // If the hash is not in the hashtable yet, create an array to hold entries with this hash
    if(!array_key_exists($currHash, $hashBuffer))
    {
        $hashBuffer[$currHash] = [];
    }
    else // If this hash is already in the buffer, we have a duplicate - add it to the  $duplicateHashes array
    {
        $duplicateHashes[$hash] = $currHash;
    }

    // Add the record to the hash buffer
    $hashBuffer[$currHash][] = $currRecord;
}

foreach($duplicateHashes as $currDuplicateHash)
{
    $duplicateRecords = array_merge($duplicateRecords, $hashBuffer[$currDuplicateHash]);
}

print_r($duplicateRecords);
```

That's a lot of ugly procedural code, so it may be good idea to encapsulate it in some sort of helper class.

```
<?php

$names = [
    ['Name' => 'John Smith', 'ID' => 65],
    ['Name' => 'Richard Johnson', 'ID' => 96],
    ['Name' => 'John Smith', 'ID' => 1105]
];

$duplicateRecords = UserRecordHelper::getDuplicateRecords($names);

print_r($duplicateRecords);

class UserRecordHelper
{
    public static function getDuplicateRecords($records)
    {
        // This map will be an populated with all records, keyed by hash
        $hashBuffer = [];

        // Buffer for hashes that are associated with more than one record
        $duplicateHashes = [];

        // This will be populated with the duplicate records
        $duplicateRecords = [];


        // Iterate through all of the records
        foreach ($records as $currRecord)
        {
            // Generate a has for the record
            $currHash = self::generateHashForUserRecord($currRecord);

            // If the hash is not in the hashtable yet, create an array to hold entries with this hash
            if (!array_key_exists($currHash, $hashBuffer))
            {
                $hashBuffer[$currHash] = [];
            }
            else // If this hash is already in the buffer, we have a duplicate - add it to the  $duplicateHashes array
            {
                $duplicateHashes[$hash] = $currHash;
            }

            // Add the record to the hash buffer
            $hashBuffer[$currHash][] = $currRecord;
        }

        foreach ($duplicateHashes as $currDuplicateHash)
        {
            $duplicateRecords = array_merge($duplicateRecords, $hashBuffer[$currDuplicateHash]);
        }

        return $duplicateRecords;
    }

    public static function generateHashForUserRecord($record)
    {
        return sha1($record['Name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the hash. Names are directly comparable.

Comment: @El_Vanja it does go against the YAGNI principle, but on the other hand... you *might* be gonna need it.

Comment: Yeah, in this case you can do that, but usually you would have more logic - more fields, etc. You would probably at least want to make all characters upper or lowercase before hashing, etc. You could even just return the bare name string from the function.  

The point is that you want to have a well defined single point of determination of equality between records. Hashing for determinition of equality in a collection is typically The Way This Is Done.

Comment: This seems to work great! The only problem I ran into was that it tried to allocate too much memory, but that's reasonable when trying to apply this to 16 thousand rows at once. I'll just do the comparisons in chunks at a time. Thanks!